# Put a WMIC query result into a variable

Tags: variables, wmic

I'm trying to put the result of:

```
"WMIC /Node:localhost /Namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 Path AntiVirusProduct get /value | find "displayName=Symantec""
```

into a variable so that I can then `ECHO` the result.

Could you please advise?

Answer (score 1):

After I spent some more time on this I found the answer. Only a "^" was needed. So command looks like:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %A IN ('WMIC /Node:localhost /Namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 Path AntiVirusProduct get /value^| find "displayName=Symantec"') DO (SET HOST=%A)
```

Then if you echo HOST -> you got it (or I got it).
Thanks anyway :D